# Matlab filter vs smoothdata

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, smoothing

I don't find a reason why the `filter` function seems to output something different than the `smoothdata` function. They both should implement a windowSize of `5` smoothing using a *moving average*. Can someone versed in these functions explain what's happening?

Here's the >[link](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html)< to the documentation, code below adapted from there, added `smoothdata` (and for additional puzzle, the `smooth` function, that is also not the same):

```
% from documentation
t = linspace(-pi,pi,100);
rng default  %initialize random number generator
x = sin(t) + 0.25*rand(size(t));
windowSize = 5;
b = (1/windowSize)*ones(1,windowSize);
a = 1;
y = filter(b,a,x);

%this is added for this example, you need >Matlab 2017a to run this
y2=smoothdata(x,'movmean',windowSize)
%y3=smooth(x,100);  %bug in the code (obsolete)
y3=smooth(x,windowSize);

%now plot data
figure;
plot(t,x)
hold on
plot(t,y)
plot(t,y2)
plot(t,y3)
legend('Input Data','Filtered Data','smoothdata','smooth')

%show obvious parts of plot
xlim([0 3]);
ylim([0 1.25]);
```

Here's what I get as output:

[image: WTF]

Here's some inconsistency in the first part of the plot:

```
%this is added for this example, you need >Matlab 2017a to run this
y2 = smoothdata(x,'movmean',[windowSize-1,0]);
y3 =  smoothdata(padarray(x,[0 2]),'movmean',[windowSize-1,0]);
%now plot data
figure(1); clf;
plot(t,x)
hold on
plot(t(1:10),y(1:10))
plot(t(1:10),y2(1:10))
plot(t(1:10),y3(1:10))

legend('Input Data','Filtered Data','smoothdata',['padded ' char(10) 'smoothdata'])

%show obvious parts of plot
xlim([-3.1784   -2.3858]);
```

[image: WTF2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`window` parameter for `smoothdata`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/smoothdata.html#bvhejau-window), if scalar, yields a window centered around the origin. `filter` implements a causal filter, meaning that it takes the mean of `windowSize` previous samples. Thus, the difference between these two results is a shift of `windowSize/2` samples. You can see this shift clearly in your plot. Use two parameters to simulate the result of `filter`:

```
y2 = smoothdata(x,'movmean',[windowSize-1,0])
```

The [`smooth` function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/smooth.html) also implements a moving average, the second parameter is the window size. You are using `100` here, instead of `windowSize`, which has a value of `5`. Thus, this result is the average over 20 times as many values. Replicate the result using the right window size:

```
y3 = smooth(x,windowSize);
```

I presume `y3` will be shifted w.r.t. the `filter` result, just like `y2` was in the question.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and example code (that works flawlessly). I did not know about causal filters. The windowSize `100` in the `smooth` function was a mistake, I adapted the example.

Comment: Upon meticulous inspection I noticed the traces are not *exactly* the same (i.e. `isequal` will return `false` for the two traces) in the first (and last) few ticks. Ideas how to resolve that issue?

Comment: @user2305193: they probably use different boundary conditions (i.e. they fill out missing data outside the input range differently). `filter` adds zeros. You can replicate that by padding the input signal with `padarray`.

Comment: @user2305193: Yes, now remove the first two points from the result on the padded data `y3`, as those are the padding -- you extended the input signal with 2 points on the left and two on the right, so the output has two additional points on the left and two additional points on the right.

Comment: I don't get it, it doesn't work, also not for `windowSize=6` and cutting away `3` values on left/right.

Comment: `isequal` is not the tool to use to compare these two results.  The two functions use different algorithms for computing a moving average.  Namely, `smoothdata` uses `movmean`, which has a specialized algorithm for computing a moving average, where `filter` is computing a generalized filtering operation using a filter of `1/N*ones(N,1)`.  The results will be numerically *equivalent*, but not necessarily bit-for-bit identical.

Comment: I understand. I used the plot in the example, to compare the first values though.

Comment: @user2305193: I realize now that in this case you need to pad the data with 4 zeros to the left, rather that 2 on each side. I was thinking of the centered filter earlier,  it you are using the causal filter.